# jQuery onchange select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<select id='list'>
    <option value='1'>First</option>
    <option value='2'>Second</option>
    <option value='3'>Third </option>
</select> 
<input type ="text" id="text"/>
```

and then this JavaScript

```
 //other variables are also declared here
    var x1 = 5;
    var x2 = 10;
    var value = x1 * x2;
    var list_value =$("#list").change(function() {
             $(this).val();
 // just an example of how i want the function in the variable 
    });
    var nwval = value * list_value;
      $('#text').val(nwval);
// some long piece of code 
// i'm also using the list_value value somewhere in the long piece of code..
```

I want the val in the textbox to change as the user selects an option, I know it'll work if I wrap the change event around it, but is there any way to go about this while keeping it as that variable `list_value`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/BXu26/1/

Comment: I understand but that's the reason i'm asking for help :)

Comment: @epascarello just because you know it doesn't mean he can, so instead of critiquing his lack of knowledge try enriching it instead...

Comment: $(selector).change() will return $(selector) back to you. so list_value is actually you select element. You need to modify that part first.

Comment: Thank you all that answered, they're really awesome people on here. I'm currently trying them out and ill get back to you guys..           Thanks again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var x1 = 5;
var x2 = 10;
var value = x1 * x2;
var nwval;
$("#list").change(function() {
    nwval = value * $(this).val();
    $('#text').val(nwval);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#text').val($('option:selected').text());
$('#list').change(function(){

        $('#text').val($('option:selected').text());
})
```

check from here http://jsfiddle.net/QrHUN/

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the change event is the better way as it creates a closure, you could use global variables as below, but you would be better (imho) to simply grab the value again futher down.

You could technically do (although a bad idea as it is global variables):

```
var x1 = 5;
var x2 = 10;
var value = x1 * x2;
var list_value = 1;
$("#list").change(function() {
    list_value = $(this).val();
    var nwval = value * list_value;
    $('#text').val(nwval); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this returns a jQuery object, not a value.

```
var list_value =$("#list").change(function() {
```

If you want the value outside of the code, you would need to do something like this

```
var list_value = 0;
var sel = $("#list").change(function() {
         list_value = $(this).val();
}).change();
var nwval = value * list_value;
$('#text').val(nwval);
```

BUT the onchange event will never update the page, just that variable!